# Wifi Configuration wlan0 unassociated

Tags: networking, wifi

Using: Model B Version 2

Dongle: TP-Link model TL-WN823N

os: raspbian

Tutorial: http://www.circuitbasics.com/raspberry-pi-wifi-installing-wifi-dongle/

Following the tutorial above i have altered the files:

> /etc/network/interfaces
>
> /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

Despite hours of my best(though limited in ability) efforts, i cannot get the pi connected to the internet through the wifi.

I assume that dongle works, and is compatible with my pi as i can use the command to return a list of wireless networks:

`sudo iwlist wlan0 scan`

the two files have been altered to show:

```
#/etc/network/interfaces    
auto lo

iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

and

```
#/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant
ctrl_interface_group=0
update_config=1

network={
    ssid="YOUR WIFI NETWORK NAME"
    psk="YOUR WIFI PASSWORD"
}
```

i simplified the later after seeing it was possible on websites offering similar tutorials.  When i type iwconfig i get:

> wlan0    unassociated    nickname:"WIFI@Realtec"

Any help with this situation would be appreciated.

In my rage i have also managed to hide the network icon on the GUI, bonus points for how to turn that back on...

EDIT:  I've now come code which works, but i'm unsure of why the initial bit did not, will be happy to accept an answer which can tell me this.  I've also added the code i'm now using below to help anyone like myself who could end up here from google.

Comment: By using `dhcp` you have caused the software which runs the network icon to disable itself. What you have in your "answer" may have been OK in 2012, but Rasbpian has changed since. See [How do I set up networking/WiFi/Static IP](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697)

Comment: Thanks, i will update as per your answer on the other question.  Regarding this though, in the link you use here: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/wireless-cli.md 

it says "Go to the bottom of the file and add the following:" followed by ssid and psk.  Are the first 3 lines of my wpa_supplicant adequate?

Comment: The answer also says If you have changed `/etc/network/interfaces`  PUT IT BACK.  Using `dhcp` disables `dhcpcd`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how I solved this problem.  Took a while to figure out so hopefully this post helps somebody.

1. Connect your Raspberry Pi 3+ to your Router with an Ethernet cable.  Run `sudo apt-get update` and then `sudo apt-get upgrade`.  This should just work out of the box.
2. Run `sudo iwlist wlan0 scanning | grep ESSID`.  If your WiFi name is there then move on to next step.
3. Run `wpa_passphrase "mywireless_ssid" "yourpassphrase" | sudo tee -a /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`.  This will add create something like this in your wpa_supplicant.conf file:

   ```
   network={
       ssid="SSID"
       #psk="PASSPHRASE"
       psk=38497220976092fc2707a838e4d4385019256149f99f935be22c90159d3b8373
   }
   ```
4. Delete the `#psk="PASSPHRASE"` line and save the file.
5. Then make sure your `/etc/network/interfaces` file looks like this:

   ```
   auto lo

   iface lo inet loopback
   iface eth0 inet dhcp

   allow-hotplug wlan0
   auto wlan0


   iface wlan0 inet dhcp
   wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
   ```
6. Then reboot the pi `sudo reboot`
7. Then hopefully you can run `ifconfig` and your `wlan0` will have ip address.

A lot of this I got from this [post](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/wireless-cli.md).

Comment: Note that the whole purpose of `wpa_passphrase` is to avoid storing your WiFi password in cleartext, but supplying a password on the command line will store it in bash history file.

Comment: Just to be clear, that the wpa_supplicant tool stores the settings in `wp_supplicant.conf` not `wpa_supplicant.conf`. The latter stores different information

Answer (score 0):

No sooner have i posted the question than i have found the answer.

```
auto lo

iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp

allow-hotplug wlan0
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
wpa-ssid “ENTER YOUR ROUTER'S SSID HERE”
wpa-psk “ENTER YOUR ROUTER'S PASSWORD KEY HERE”
```

This can be found here:
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=31&t=26558